# Cannot check for MySQL Daemon startup because of mysqladmin failure

Tags: mysql

My server (redhat enterprise Linux 5.11) recently crashed. After bringing it back up MySQL would not start. I keep getting the message "Cannot check for MySQL Daemon startup because of mysqladmin failure." I have uninstalled and reinstalled MySQL using yum and the redhat repository with no success. I have searched for several hours with no success. Any article I find relating to the problem all say to reinstall, which is not working for me.

The MySQL installation consists of:
mysql-5.0.95-5.el5_9.i386,
perl-DBD-MySQL-3.0007-2.el5.i386,
mysql-server-5.0.95-5.el5_9.i386, and
php53-mysql-5.3.3-26.el5_11.i386

How can I fix this?

Also if I try a command like MySQL -U root -p I get the message "Bus error."

Comment: Have you run `mysqlcheck`? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlcheck.html

Comment: No since MySQL wont even start thus it's not accessing any tables to my knowledge. Is there a flag to check for start failures?

Answer (score 0):

First, run updatedb to get a current index of the files on your system. Then run -> locate mysqld | grep error.log.  Check the log to see if there is more information.

I would also run -> locate mysqladmin  and see what the time stamp is on the file. I have seen packages in the past that did not include mysqladmin and I had to install it as a separate .rpm.  Your reinstall might have put it in a different location and you have two of them.  Your system path might lead to the previous one always getting called.

Comment: /usr/bin/mysqladmin file is dated jan 8 2013.

Comment: I checked after uninstalling MySQL that all the MySQL files in usr/bin were removed, including mysqladmin and then created again after the install. Not sure why the date remained jan 8 2013.

Comment: take a look at /var/log/messages and see if there is anything there about mysqld.  What happens when you run service mysqld start on the command line?

Comment: /sbin/service mysqld start

Cannot check for MySQL Daemon startup because of mysqladmin failure.
Starting mysqld:                                           [FAILED]

Comment: when I try to start mysqld the messages log reports the following: Jan 29 23:46:03 finaid45 kernel: cciss 0000:0a:00.0: cciss: c f7a00260 has CHECK CONDITION sense key = 0x3
Jan 29 23:46:04 finaid45 kernel: cciss 0000:0a:00.0: cciss: c f7a00000 has CHECK CONDITION sense key = 0x3
Jan 29 23:46:06 finaid45 last message repeated 3 times
Jan 29 23:46:06 finaid45 kernel: cciss 0000:0a:00.0: cciss: c f7a00260 has CHECK CONDITION sense key = 0x3

Comment: Yikes.  Bad, very bad.  This relates to an inode or block error on your hard drive.  It appears that a file system check   efsck   needs to be run on that drive.

Comment: I have done that already and it fixed what was found. Does it keep writing to the same bad blocks.

Comment: What switches did you use on the command?  You may need to use a lower level disk repair utility.  If it was a bad crash, a new disk drive may be your best option.

Answer (score 0):

Replacement drives were the solution. Two drives had failed. Short tests and status reports claimed all drives were good. Not until the very end of a long sequential test, was it reported that drives 2 and 4 had problems. Once I replaced the drives MySQL started up fine, after yet another uninstall and reinstall. Thanks for all the responses.